# How to deploy a Java Game on my personal website?

Tags: java, web-deployment, java-web-start

I built a Java game for a CS class. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/waiwaikim/shoot_them_up). The main class is Game.Java found [here](https://github.com/waiwaikim/shoot_them_up/tree/master/src/_08final_raster/mvc/controller). I have a simple static website hosted on GoDaddy found [here](https://waiwaikim.com/). I would like to allow a visitor to my website to play the game on a web browser I don't have a server yet, so I'll buy a basic 
VPS through GoDaddy. Besides that, what's the best way to go about it? I think Applet is no longer supported by Chrome. Is Java Web Start the only way now? I would prefer if the visitor doesn't have to download anything. Any supporting material or YouTube video would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 4):

Java is no longer supported by *any* modern browser, so the only way people will be able to play your game is to either include a client-side, JS/WASM-based library that sets up a complete JVM and then running the game inside of that on your page, or by giving people a link to your game's `.jar` file, so that they can download and run it on their own computer.